# Vertical alignment of text in node spanned over multiple matrix columns

Tags: tikz-pgf

The problem with the following MWE is that I don't understand why the text in the big node isn't aligned in the center (vertically speaking).

How can I do that?

### Picture

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{
tikz,
relsize,
tgheros
}

\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,
    decorations.pathreplacing,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    decorations.shapes,
    decorations.text,
    shapes,
    shapes.geometric,
    shapes.symbols,
    matrix,
    patterns,
    intersections,
    fit
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\tikzset{
    >=latex,
    line/.style={draw, thick, ->},
    phase/.style={
        align=left,
        anchor=center,
        rectangle,
        %drop shadow={opacity=0.5},
        %   minimum width=2cm,
        minimum height=1.0cm,
        %   text width=6cm,
        font=\sffamily\bfseries\small,
        draw=black,
        very thick,
        fill=black!40,
        %top color=white,
        %bottom color=white!20!blue
    },
    phasentext/.style={
        align=left,
        anchor=center,
        %node distance=0.5cm,
        rectangle,
        %drop shadow={opacity=0.5},
        %rounded corners, 
        minimum width=2cm,
        minimum height=1cm, 
        %   text width=7cm,
        draw=gray,
        very thick,
        %fill=black!20,
        %shade,
        font=\sffamily\small,
        %top color=white!80!black,
        %bottom color=white
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,node distance=0.5cm]
\matrix (Versuchsplan) [
matrix of nodes,
nodes in empty cells,
row sep=6mm,
column sep=3mm,
inner sep=7pt
] {
    %
    |[phase]| 1 & & & & \\
    & |[phasentext] (WordA)| Testa: \tikz \draw[thick, circular glow={fill=gray}] (0,0) circle [radius=6pt]; &
    |[phasentext] (WordB)| Stuff: \tikz \draw[very thick, drop shadow] (0.2,0.1) rectangle (0.7,0.2); &
    |[phasentext] (WordC)| Stuff text word: \begin{tikzpicture} \draw[thick] (0,0) circle [radius=6pt]; \draw[thick,fill=black] (0,0) circle [radius=0.5pt]; \end{tikzpicture} &
    |[phasentext] (WordD)| Some more words: \begin{tikzpicture} \draw[thick] (0,0) circle [radius=6pt]; \draw[thick] (-3pt,-2pt) -- (3pt,-2pt) -- (0,2pt) -- cycle; \draw[thick] (0,2pt) -- (0,-2pt); \end{tikzpicture} \\
};
\node[phase, fit=(Versuchsplan-1-2)(Versuchsplan-1-5), align=left, anchor=center] (Words) {Longs text I suppose};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the PGF-TikZ Manual for version `3.0.0` (pag. 68 sec. 5.1), you have to manually adjust `text height` and `text depth`. In the following code I added red lines to highlight the correct vertical displacement.

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{
tikz,
relsize,
tgheros
}

\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,
    decorations.pathreplacing,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    decorations.shapes,
    decorations.text,
    shapes,
    shapes.geometric,
    shapes.symbols,
    matrix,
    patterns,
    intersections,
    fit
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\tikzset{
    >=latex,
    line/.style={draw, thick, ->},
    phase/.style={text height=1.5ex,text depth=2ex,%<-- Here's the trick
        align=left,
        anchor=center,
        rectangle,
        %drop shadow={opacity=0.5},
        %   minimum width=2cm,
        minimum height=1.0cm,
        %   text width=6cm,
        font=\sffamily\bfseries\small,
        draw=black,
        very thick,
        fill=black!40,
        %top color=white,
        %bottom color=white!20!blue
    },
    phasentext/.style={
        align=left,
        anchor=center,
        %node distance=0.5cm,
        rectangle,
        %drop shadow={opacity=0.5},
        %rounded corners, 
        minimum width=2cm,
        minimum height=1cm, 
        %   text width=7cm,
        draw=gray,
        very thick,
        %fill=black!20,
        %shade,
        font=\sffamily\small,
        %top color=white!80!black,
        %bottom color=white
    }
}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,node distance=0.5cm]
    \matrix (Versuchsplan) [
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes in empty cells,
    row sep=6mm,
    column sep=3mm,
    inner sep=7pt
    ] {
        %
        |[phase] (1)| 1 & & & & \\
        & |[phasentext] (WordA)| Testa: \tikz \draw[thick, circular glow={fill=gray}] (0,0) circle [radius=6pt]; &
        |[phasentext] (WordB)| Stuff: \tikz \draw[very thick, drop shadow] (0.2,0.1) rectangle (0.7,0.2); &
        |[phasentext] (WordC)| Stuff text word: \begin{tikzpicture} \draw[thick] (0,0) circle [radius=6pt]; \draw[thick,fill=black] (0,0) circle [radius=0.5pt]; \end{tikzpicture} &
        |[phasentext] (WordD)| Some more words: \begin{tikzpicture} \draw[thick] (0,0) circle [radius=6pt]; \draw[thick] (-3pt,-2pt) -- (3pt,-2pt) -- (0,2pt) -- cycle; \draw[thick] (0,2pt) -- (0,-2pt); \end{tikzpicture} \\
    };
    \node[phase, fit=(Versuchsplan-1-2)(Versuchsplan-1-5), align=left, anchor=center] (Words) {Longs text I suppose};
    \draw [red] let \p1=(1.base),
                           \p2=(Words.base)
                in (\x1,\y1) -- ++(5cm,0)
                   (\x2,\y2) -- ++(-5cm,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. For anyone else: the code has to be added locally: `\node[phase, fit=(Versuchsplan-1-2)(Versuchsplan-1-5), align=left, anchor=center, text height=1.5ex,text depth=2ex] (Words) {Longs text I suppose};`